# VB.net restricting access to event handler within scope, or alternative

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, user-interface

I have an event handler which handles its event just fine. However, I don't want to be able to call the handler directly or, more specifically, give my fellow programmers the ability to call it directly, since I want to update nudCurrent.Value only when the laser current is set.

```vb
Public Class TestClass

    Dim WithEvents myCurrentSource As New CurrentSourceClass

    Private Sub TestScript()
        'among other things, sets current to 85
        myCurrentSource.SetCurrent(85)
    End Sub

    Private Sub handleLaserCurrentSet() Handles myCurrentSource.LaserCurrentSet
        Me.nudCurrent.Value = myCurrentSource.GetCurrent()
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class CurrentSourceClass

    Public Event LaserCurrentSet()

    Private currentSet As Double = Double.NaN

    Public Sub SetCurrent(ByVal dCurrentAmps As Double)
        ' set the current on the current source here
        Me.currentSet = dCurrentAmps
        ' then raise the event
        RaiseEvent LaserCurrentSet()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetCurrent() As Double
        Return Me.currentSet
    End Function

End Class
```

I can't think of a way to restrict the access to the event handler routine within its scope, so I'm looking for an alternate way of doing this. What is the best practice?

*I understand that I could just put `me.nudCurrent.Value = 85` after setting the current, but I like the neatness of the event driven UI updates. Can I have my cake and eat it too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an anonymous event handler

```
AddHandler myCurrentSource.LaserCurrentSet,
                Sub()
                    Me.nudCurrent.Value = myCurrentSource.GetCurrent()
                End Sub
```

But keep in mind that the value can be set from anywhere inside the class. You cannot restrict that.